# Access web app with azure and external DB

Tags: asp.net, azure

Is it possible to use azure with local/external db for saving users. So is there some option/pattern where you can setup azure to use your own external database for checking user credentials?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Azure doesn't limit external connections unless you put some type of limit in place (e.g. blocking outbound connections). As far as accessing an external database, again, Azure has nothing to do with that; that's about your own firewall etc.

Comment: Ok, so basically I have database with User table, which have fields like Username, Email, Password etc. So can I set up Azure so that when it get request "login with that username-password" it look into my table and to checks against it. Of couse by password I mean hash.

Comment: (sorry about prior comment - meant for another question). I'm still not sure what you're getting at. What's stopping you from changing your connection string to point to an external database? Also, you should be editing your question, not placing details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to access your local on-premises SQL Server database from a web app in Azure App Service, you can try to achieve it by using [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server).

[image]